# How to make the grouping fastest, provided that the data in the array also show the object nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello this is my array;

```
arr =[{cNo:1,buyOrSel:'A',ip:192.168.1.1},{cNo:1,buyOrSel:'S',ip:192.168.1.1},{cNo:2,buyOrSel:'S',ip:192.168.1.2},{cNo:3,buyOrSel:'A',ip:192.168.1.1},{cNo:4,buyOrSel:'S',ip:192.168.1.3},{cNo:5,buyOrSel:'S',ip:192.168.1.2}]
```

I want to group in Object like this;

```
[{cNo:'1,3',ip:192.168.1.1},{cNo:'2,5',ip:192.168.1.2}]
```

I don't want to use nested For loop.What is the best way for this ?

Comment: your array isnt a valid one..

Comment: you wanna group by ip ?

Comment: ok. but your group condition is not clear here.

Comment: yes I want to group by ip but same like my Object

Comment: so why not cNo:'4'? You need to clarify what the condition is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let arr = [{cNo:1,buyOrSel:'A',ip:"192.168.1.1"},{cNo:1,buyOrSel:'S',ip:"192.168.1.1"},{cNo:2,buyOrSel:'S',ip:"192.168.1.2"},{cNo:3,buyOrSel:'A',ip:"192.168.1.1"},{cNo:4,buyOrSel:'S',ip:"192.168.1.3"},{cNo:5,buyOrSel:'S',ip:"192.168.1.2"}];

arr = arr.reduce((prev, a) => {
  let cNo = prev[a.ip] = prev[a.ip] || [];

  if (cNo.indexOf(a.cNo) < 0) {
    prev[a.ip].push(a.cNo);
  };
  return prev
}, {});

arr = Object.keys(arr).map(key => {
  return {
    cNo: arr[key].join(),
    ip: key
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use object for better grouping.
and instead of pushing only cNo, you can push whole object too.

```
let arr = [{cNo:1,buyOrSel:'A',ip:"192.168.1.1"},{cNo:1,buyOrSel:'S',ip:"192.168.1.1"},{cNo:2,buyOrSel:'S',ip:"192.168.1.2"},{cNo:3,buyOrSel:'A',ip:"192.168.1.1"},{cNo:4,buyOrSel:'S',ip:"192.168.1.3"},{cNo:5,buyOrSel:'S',ip:"192.168.1.2"}];

let objectByIP = {};

arr.forEach(element => {
  if (!objectByIP[element.ip]) {
    objectByIP[element.ip] = [element.cNo];
  } else {
    objectByIP[element.ip].push(element.cNo);
  }
});

console.log(objectByIP);
console.log(Object.keys(objectByIP));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use map():

let a = arr.map(a=>{ return {cNo: a.cNo, ip: a.ip}})

Comment: will return same array as input.

Comment: @Excalibur look at the result he wants . there is no filter option just droping "buyOrSel" from incoming array. if there is some specification he must explain about the logic